# PySpark Outputting '01/01/0001' and '12/31/9999' Incorrectly in Parquet

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I am using PySpark 3.0.1 to generate parquet files.

When executing the following command

```
sparkDF.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(file_name)
```

The `9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000` datetime is written as `1816-03-29 11:56:08.066277376` in the parquet file.

The `0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000` datetime is written as `1754-08-29 04:43:41.128654848` in the parquet file.

In contrast, `sparkDF.write.mode("overwrite").csv(file_name)` outputs the correct datetime value in CSV format.

Does anybody know what is going on? Thanks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Are you sure you're reading correct parquet files?

Comment: How are  you reading the data back?  This looks very similar to the issues discussed in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69458623/pyarrow-parquet-saving-large-timestamp-incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is whatever system you are reading them with is likely misinterpreting or has an overflow issue with handling the int96 timestamp format.  You can write a more standard format as:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.outputTimestampType", "TIMESTAMP_MICROS")
data_frame.write.parquet("path")
```

(Credit: [How to save spark dataframe to parquet without using INT96 format for timestamp columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56582539/how-to-save-spark-dataframe-to-parquet-without-using-int96-format-for-timestamp))